# Android: connect to Wifi using terminal

Tags: android, bash, terminal, netsh, iwconfig

On Windows I can connect to a specific Wifi using:

```
netsh wlan connect ssid=SSID1
```

The command `iwconfig` doesn't work on Android. The command `svc wifi enable` just turns the Wifi on. Is there a terminal command for Android that connect to a specific Wifi? I'm using a rooted Cyanogenmod 13.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the Kali Linux overlay for Android if it's availible for your phone. It supports the `iwconfig` command and can connect to (password protected) wifi networks via the Nethunter Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply connect to WiFi - you can use Termux only.

This video can help installing Termux on your Android phone:
https://youtu.be/-oE8_bXVn4M

In Termux:

Enabling WiFi:

```
TERMUX-wifi-enable
```

Search available networks:

```
TERMUX-wifi-scaninfo
```

Connect to WiFi:

```
TERMUX-wifi-connect [SSID] [encryption type (none|wep|wpa|)] [key]
```